# CGAffineTransform causes subviews to move abruptly

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, core-graphics

I have a custom "card" view which has a corresponding XIB that lays out the subviews. I'm using constraints to layout the subviews.

I add the card view to another view and then attempt to animate it using `CGAffineTransform rotationAngle`.

When I trigger the animation, the subviews of the card view shift suddenly depending on the rotationAngle.  Meanwhile, the rest of the animation works as expected; it rotates at the angle I specified.

My questions are: why are the subviews changing position when the transform begins and how do I prevent that from happening?

Here's a sample of the code I'm using.  `view.layoutIfNeeded()` and `view.autoresizesSubviews` do not seem to make a difference, FYI.

```
        let rotation = arc4random_uniform(20)
        let destinationCenterY = self.frame.height + view.frame.height
        let destinationCenterX = arc4random_uniform(UInt32(self.frame.width))
        let startTransform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat(rotation))

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.4, animations: {
            view.transform = startTransform
            view.center.y = destinationCenterY
            view.center.x = CGFloat(destinationCenterX)
            view.layoutIfNeeded()
            view.autoresizesSubviews = true
        }, completion: { (complete) in
            view.removeFromSuperview()
            view.transform = endTransform
        })
```

I also have a strange issue with subviews resizing when using `CGAffineTransform scale`. Any help would be much appreciated.

EDIT:
Adding images of what is happening.
Before animation, views are aligned properly:
[image: before]
After animation starts, the subviews move to the right:
[image: after]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prevent my subviews from moving around on me when a transform started, I had to iterate through the subviews and set `view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true`, as follows:

```
for subview in view.subviews {
    subview.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true
}
```

Thanks, @DevB2F for pointing me in the right direction!

Answer (score 1):

when using auto layout, before animating you need to set :

```
  view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true
```

Comment: I tried this an it had no effect.  I updated the original question with some screenshots